# How to deal with working papers when quoting?

Tags: publications

I am a doctoral student and therefore have only little experience in publishing.
Now I ask myself how I should deal with working papers of other researchers in my articles.
I have read some interesting working papers and would like to quote them in my article. However, I am not sure if I should do so. Since these working papers have never been published and reviewed in a journal, I do not know if citing them is useful or even allowed.
On the other hand there are interesting results in these articles, which I would like to mention.

So I would like to ask how I can best deal with working papers when citing.

Can I easily include and quote them in my text?

Or should I better not do so, because I would like to submit my own article later in a respected journal?

Answer (score 2):

You can cite any manuscript, public or private, be it a work-in-progress, technical report, or  peer-reviewed publication. Relevant results should be cited and, when building upon them, they must be.